# Setting App from ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a general question about how to write my app properly.
I got my data from the server and then I want to start setting the objects
preferably on the global scope if possible.
How do I manage that without async: false (I read that it is a bad practice)? 
what is the correct way?

```
var people = {
   url: 'api/myapp/data.json'
   name: '',
   lastName: '',
   age: 0
}

var someFuncWithLastName(){
 //some use of the data that I got from the server
 //people.lastName suppose...after it got the correct data from the ajax res
}

//Get Data from server 
var getData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/myapp/data.json',
        success: function(res){ 
           people = res 
           // res = { url:'api/myapp/data.json', name:'John', lastName:'Snow', age:34}
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: General question about how to write e.g. an app is off-topic here at SO. [codereview.se] or [softwareengineering.se] might be a better place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are the correct way to go (You should never pollute the global scope):

```
function someFuncWithLastName (){
  //some use of the data that I got from the server
  //people.lastName suppose...
  getDataForChart().then(data => {
     console.log(data);
  }
}

//Get Data from server 
var getDataForChart = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/myapp/data.json',
    });
}
```

With new es6 await syntax, you can even make this easier:

```
function someFuncWithLastName() {
  //some use of the data that I got from the server
  //people.lastName suppose...
  const data = await getDataForChart();

  console.log(data);
}

//Get Data from server 
var getDataForChart = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/myapp/data.json',
    });
}
```

Without knowing more, it's hard to tell you more. You can consider using a class:

```js
// Helper function for simulating an AJAX call
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

class Person {
  constructor(name, lastName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  
  async getChartData() {
    console.log(`Making call to /api/myapp/data.json?${this.name}`);
    
    await delay(2000);
    
    return {some: 'a', sample: 'b', data: 'c'};
  }
  
  async getOtherData() {
    console.log(`Making call to /api/myapp/otherData.json?${this.name}`);
    
    await delay(3000);
    
    return {more: 'x', data: 'y'};
  }
}

const person = new Person('John', 'Doe');

// These do not block (Functionally almost identical to using Promise.all in an async function)
// person.getChartData().then(data => console.log('Data Returned: ', data));
// person.getOtherData().then(data => console.log('Data Returned: ', data));

async function main() {
  // These will "block" (Not really blocking, just waiting before continuing with the rest)
  console.log('== await each ==');
  const data = await person.getChartData();
  console.log(data);
  
  const otherData = await person.getOtherData();
  console.log(otherData);
  
  console.log('== Run concurrently ==');
  
  const [data2, otherData2] = await Promise.all([person.getChartData(), person.getOtherData()]);
  
  console.log('All data returned', data2, otherData2);
}

// Call the main function (This does not block the main thread)
main();
```

Comment: Ok. First of all thanks FrankerZ. 
2 questions about it:
1. await - Isn't it stopping the all application until the data got from the server?
2. Promises - so if I have a lot of other functions, and actually all the app functions and variables depend on that data, so all the functions will be with await / then?

Comment: When you make an ajax call, anything after that await will not be run until that ajax call completes. While that may cause your app to "stop" (Because nothing after that statement will execute until the code finishes), it's not actually blocking the main thread (Which is used by your browser to actually render elements on the screen). You can run multiple calls in order without actually blocking, and if you don't "await" it, you can still use it without actually blocking anything. (I'll clarify a bit in my class example)